# python-requests: order get parameters

Tags: python, http-request, python-requests

I am implementing a client library for a private HTTP-API using [python requests](http://python-requests.org). The API(which I don't control) expects the parameters to be in a certain order, but python-requests doesn't honor a sorted dict as parameter.

This is what i tried:

```
import requests
from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict

params = SortedDict()
params['s'] = 'value1'
params['f'] = 'value2'

requests.get('https://example.org/private_api', params=params)
#performs request as https://example.org/private_api?f=value1&s=value2
```

This is what I am trying to avoid:

```
requests.get('https://example.org?{0}'.format(urlencode(params)))
```

Comment: Why do you use `data` param instead of `params` when doing get request?

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost: That was an error when I compiled the example.

Comment: Why is this an issue? GET parameters are usually accessed by name not by order.

Comment: Because I don't control the API and that's the way they expect it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently requests doesn't allow to do this as you wish. This is of course shortcoming that will be [fixed](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/179). However as `params` parameter can take not only dictionary but bytes as well you should be able to do something in between:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from urllib import urlencode
import requests

params = OrderedDict([('first', 1), ('second', 2), ('third', 3)])
requests.get('https://example.org/private_api', params=urlencode(params))
```

This doesn't work as I see due to bug in line 85 of models.py: `self.params = dict(params or []`.
I raised this problem in issue [Wrong handling of params given as bytes object](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/349)

Comment: Thanks, I finally marked this as the solution as it provides the solution that is applicable in the foreseeable future.

Comment: @TillBackhaus Already [fixed](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/commit/9e953f33209545bbbd338e06fb2abc2c62c13212).

Comment: What version does this work for? When I tried it in both `1.2.3` and `2.0.0`, `requests.get('http://example.org/private_api', params=urlencode(params)).request.body` returned `None`

Answer (score 28):

The requests lib now supports this out-of-the-box: To get ordered parameters you use a sequence of two-valued tuples instead. This eliminates the additional requirement of OrderedDict.

```
payload = (('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'))
r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params=payload)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
1.2.3
>>> payload = (('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'), ('key3', 'value3'))
>>> r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params=payload)
>>> print r.json()['url']
http://httpbin.org/get?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

Answer (score 2):

It used with version 2.2.0:

```
import requests
yourparams = {'s' : 'value1', 'f': 'value2'}

test = requests.get('https://example.org/private_api', params=yourparams)
print(test.url)
```

More details? Kindly check in [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

Comment: This does not preserve order of params which was requested by OP.

Answer (score 1):

Line 85 of `requests/models.py` ([link](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/develop/requests/models.py)) turns the `params` object into a plain `dict`, rather than the `SortedDict` you passed in. I don't think you will be able to do what you want, unless you patch the library.

```
self.params = dict(params or [])
```

Comment: Considering the options at I think I'll have to go with what I was trying to avoid then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works in `1.2.3` as well as `2.0.0`

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'2.0.0'
>>> data = [('first', 1), ('second', 2), ('third', 3)]
>>> requests.get('http://example.org/private_api', data=data).request.body
'first=1&second=2&third=3'
```